# Cannot convert from X to Fragment if the base class is derived from Fragment in another project

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a wip Framework project in which I derived the Fragment class creating OnlineFragment.
In my current app project I created the Account class who inherits OnlineFragment without any problems
but when I try to instantiate in the main activity
    Fragment frag = new Account();

I get this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Account to Fragment

here the classes definitions

project: com.x.framework

```
public class OnlineFragment extends Fragment {
```

project: com.x.app

```
public class Account extends OnlineFragment {
```

Comment: Probably you have wrong imports.

Comment: found it, the activity is using support.v4.fragments and it seems the only way to have tabs+swype, I created it with the project wizard targeting 4.2.2 with a min sdk of 4.0

Comment: @codareee no, thats not the only way to have tabs+swipe. (its the IDE doing stupid stuff) if you use the v7-support-library, you can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` with "real" Fragments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its because you are importing the wrong Fragment package 
import support.v4.fragment package

Answer (score 0):

I was using two different fragments at the same time app.fragment and support.v4.fragment