# Change type of X fragment to Y fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, type-mismatch

I want to implement a 3-Tab Activity/fragment from another activity/fragment.

I have looked in many links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590479/cannot-convert-from-x-to-fragment-if-the-base-class-is-derived-from-fragment-in)
 , [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212994/how-to-fix-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-android-app-fragmentmanager-to-an) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003463/type-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-registerfragment-to-fragment) but none of them solved my problem. The problem comes in `StudentProfile.java` file in the code

```
 fragment = new RandomFragment();
```

The error is: Type mismatch: cannot convert from RandomFragment to Fragment

StudentProfile.java

```
package com.nikhil.studentlife;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.nikhil.studentlife.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.nikhil.studentlife.model.NavDrawerItem;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
//import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StudentProfile extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] studProfile;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

    /*
     * from android hive example:--
     * 
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
     */

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_profile);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.studProfile);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.studProfile_icons);



        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        studProfile = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.studProfile);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, studProfile));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(StudentProfile.this, "Drawer Closed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(StudentProfile.this, "Drawer Opened",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        /*
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
        */

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Intent intent = getIntent();
        // String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(listView);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListener.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, studProfile[arg2] + " was selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectItem(arg2);
    }

    public void selectItem(int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listView.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
        setTitle(studProfile[arg2]);

    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    /*
     * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the
     * menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.student_profile, menu); return true; }
     * 
     * @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // Handle
     * action bar item clicks here. The action bar will // automatically handle
     * clicks on the Home/Up button, so long // as you specify a parent activity
     * in AndroidManifest.xml. int id = item.getItemId(); if (id ==
     * R.id.action_settings) { return true; } return
     * super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); }
     */
    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

     /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            //fragment = new Fragment();
            fragment = new RandomFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new HomeWorkFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AssignmentsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ProjectsFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new GamesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new ActivitiesFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            listView.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }


}
```

RandomFragment.java

package com.nikhil.studentlife;

import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class RandomFragment extends ActionBarActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener{

```
   private ViewPager tabsviewPager;
    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       tabsviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

       mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

       tabsviewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);

       getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
       getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

       Tab friendstab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Friends").setTabListener(this);
       Tab publicprofiletab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Public").setTabListener(this);
       Tab communitytab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Community").setTabListener(this);

       getSupportActionBar().addTab(friendstab);
       getSupportActionBar().addTab(publicprofiletab);
       getSupportActionBar().addTab(communitytab);


       //This helps in providing swiping effect for v7 compat library 
       tabsviewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
           }

           @Override
           public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }

           @Override
           public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
       });

   }

    @Override
   public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

    @Override
   public void onTabSelected(Tab selectedtab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       tabsviewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedtab.getPosition()); //update tab position on tap
   }

    @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
```

}

Comment: Your `RandomFragment` is not a `Fragment`, it's an `Activity`.

Comment: @Android777 thanks..Please read my modified question.. can you please tell me , how to do it?